# Making a horizontal list where the items fill to the control's width in Windows 8 XAML?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

I'm making a Windows 8.1 C# app where there is a list of color blocks in a line. The number of colors can change, and I want the color blocks to fill up the width of the list control. I have tried using ItemsControl like this:

```
<ItemsControl Name="testGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,100,0,0" Width="220" Background="Black">
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Rectangle Fill="{Binding}" MinWidth="44" Height="44"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

I've tried GridView and ListView with item styles with HorizontalContentAlignment set to stretch as well. The main issue is that these are all vertical lists. I need a horizontal one.

If I try adding a StackPanel the stretched items stop working. Like this:

```
<ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
   <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
   </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
```

Here is an example image:

[image]

I'm using an item source bound to a List or Observable Collection. How would I go about achieving the effect in the image? Thanks

Comment: If it is not available you could port WPF's UniformGrid (and set rows to 1)

Comment: Will UniformGrid work in the Win 8.1 environment? Isn't that why they left it out?

Comment: Just take the source code of the UniformGrid and see for yourself. I do not know why MS left it out

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to calculate the available width and use that to evenly divide the space between all the items.
I've done what you need in a recent project, but it was done with a `ListView` instead of an `ItemsControl`.
All the calculation code is inside a custom control that inherits from `Panel`

```
public class SplitPanel : Panel
{
    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
    {
        // the final measure size is the available size for the width, and the maximum
        // desired size of our children for the height
        Size finalSize = new Size { Width = availableSize.Width };

        if (this.Children.Count != 0)
            availableSize.Width /= (double)this.Children.Count;

        foreach (var current in this.Children)
        {
            current.Measure(availableSize);

            Size desiredSize = current.DesiredSize;
            finalSize.Height = Math.Max(finalSize.Height, desiredSize.Height);
        }

        // make sure it will works in design time mode
        if (double.IsPositiveInfinity(finalSize.Height) || double.IsPositiveInfinity(finalSize.Width))
            return Size.Empty;

        return finalSize;
    }

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeSize)
    {
        Rect finalRect = new Rect(new Point(), arrangeSize);
        double width = arrangeSize.Width / this.Children.Count;

        foreach (var child in this.Children)
        {
            finalRect.Height = Math.Max(arrangeSize.Height, child.DesiredSize.Height);
            finalRect.Width = width;

            child.Arrange(finalRect);

            // move each child by the width increment 
            finalRect.X += width;
        }

        return arrangeSize;
    }
}
```

When that is defined you can use it on a `ListView` like this

```
<ListView x:Name="ImageList"
            Margin="0,10,0,0"
            Style="{StaticResource HorizontalListViewStyle}"
            ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ImageBarListViewItemStyle}"
            SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex, ElementName=MainPivot, Mode=TwoWay}"
            Grid.Row="1">
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <controls:SplitPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
</ListView>
```

It will give you this result

[image: SplitPanel]

For reference without the panel

[image: NoSplitPanel]

Comment: I had a similar requirement and it worked for me, though it resulted in UI freezing up a little.

Comment: Weird, that never happend in my app

Answer (score 0):

If it's only about displaying filled rectangles, you might put the whole thing in a `Viewbox` with fixed width and height and `Stretch` set to `Fill`:

```
<Viewbox Stretch="Fill" Width="220" Height="44">
    <ItemsControl x:Name="testGrid">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Rectangle Fill="{Binding}" MinWidth="44" Height="44"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Viewbox>
```

Comment: Note that the Viewbox scales instead of resizes. For rectangles that might be Ok but for other control it might not be

Comment: @Erno That's why I wrote "If it's only about displaying filled rectangles".

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use a `Viewbox` since it's a can of worms - though it might work. I'd use an `ItemsControl` with a custom panel used for its `ItemsPanel` template. The [`UniformGrid`](https://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WinRTXamlToolkit/WinRTXamlToolkit.Shared/Controls/UniformGrid/UniformGrid.cs) in my toolkit would almost work, but you'd need to somehow bind its `Columns` (count) property to the number of elements in a list. It should be easy to modify though to not require a `Columns` property if all you need is to equally divide the space. The [`SquareGrid`](https://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WinRTXamlToolkit/WinRTXamlToolkit.Shared/Controls/SquareGrid/SquareGrid.cs) does it that way, but it expands in both directions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use UniformGrid with Rows="1"

```
<UniformGrid Rows="1">
                <Border  Margin="5,0" Background="Red" Height="20" ></Border>
                <Border  Margin="5,0" Background="Green" Height="20" ></Border>
                <Border   Margin="5,0" Background="Black" Height="20" ></Border>
                <Border  Margin="5,0" Background="Gray" Height="20" ></Border>
                <Border  Margin="5,0" Background="Orange" Height="20" ></Border>
</UniformGrid>
```